# Aggregating a column with possible null values

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Assume we have the following data set

`+----------+
| Column 1 |
+----------+
|     NULL |
|     NULL |
|     NULL |
|     NULL |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        2 |
+----------+`

And then lets run an aggregating query of

```
select count(`Column 1`), 
`Column 1`, 
(select count(*) 
    from testingtable) as total 
from testingtable 
group by `Column 1`
```

To get the following results:

`` +-------------------+----------+-------+
| count(`Column 1`) | Column 1 | total |
+-------------------+----------+-------+
|                 0 |     NULL |    10 |
|                 4 |        1 |    10 |
|                 2 |        2 |    10 |
+-------------------+----------+-------+ ``

How come aggregating (using `count` in this case) over a null value returns `NULL` instead of `4` (in this case)? I am aware that `null = null # => null` in most SQL engines (even postgres), but shouldn't grouping handle switching to `is` when necessary? How do you need to handle this case properly?

Note: Postgres yields the same result.

Comment: Count with a column name counts the non-null values in that column. Count(*) just counts the records.

Comment: Are there any downsides to counting records compared to counting values @MikeS?

Comment: No downsides really. It's all about what you are trying to do. If you are trying to count non-null values in a field use count([fieldname]) if you are trying to count records use count records. There may be a slight performance advantage to counting records as the db doesn't have to examine values in a table but It would be exceedingly slight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `count` function contain `null` will not calculate the quantity

```
count(*)
```

instead of

```
count(`Column 1`)
```

You can try this.

```
select count(*), 
    `Column 1`, 
    (select count(*) 
        from testingtable) as total 
    from testingtable 
    group by `Column 1`
```

Comment: Sounds about right. Are there any downsides to counting records instead of values?

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a0bd/6

```
SELECT count(*), 
        `Column1`, 
        t.total 
FROM testingtable 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT count(*) as total 
     FROM testingtable 
) t
ON 1=1
GROUP BY `Column1`
```

Or I suspect you even do not need your `total` field, but just:

```
SELECT count(*), 
        `Column1`
FROM testingtable 
GROUP BY `Column1`
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Rollup seems to produce unnecessary values. What does it actually do?

Comment: It calculates total for you one time, instead of doing that on every row. Calculating `(select count(*)  from testingtable) as total` is very expensive and inefficient, on top of that it generates unnecessary data repeated in every row. As I wrote, I suspect you don't need total value in every row, you just need it once.

Comment: Yeah, the total value select was there as a comparison to actual data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without having another `select` with in `select` using `over()`

```
select distinct `column 1`, 
                 count(*) over(partition by `column 1`) as `Column 1`,
                 count(*) over() as total 
 from testingtable
```